# Symfony2 - Twig : Setting value of dropdown list using a twig variable

Tags: symfony, twig

This has been bugging me for a while...

I want to pre-select the value of a dropdown list which is being rendered by twig. I want to pre-populate it using a `twig variable` but it doesnt seem to work.

Heres my code:

```
{{ form_widget(form.identifier,{value: "{{ magCode }}" }) }}
```

The value of {{ magCode }} is "DP". If I manually type this value in, it works..

```
{{ form_widget(form.identifier,{value: "DP" }) }}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
{{ form_widget(form.identifier,{value: magCode }) }}
```

You don’t need to nest `{{ ... }}` delimiters. The ones you used to wrap `form_widget` are also used to print any other variable they contain.

Comment: Spot on.  Cheers mate!